Best way to edit a football match from 2 fixed camera/video?
I've 2 camera , each one get half pitch of a football match.
Both Video starts at the same time.
I've to produce a single video taking video from one camera then other camera, based on when "ball" is (right video, or left video).
Which is fastest way to do this ?
Thanks

Best way is probably with a multicam edit. This can be done with most major video editing software, here's instructions for Premiere and DaVinci.
Essentially, it lets you see both cameras at the same time and cut between them just by selecting that camera. You can edit at the speed of the footage, or run it faster if you're comfortable.
